# cannot find read funcation to read image from video cature object

Tags: windows, python-2.7, opencv

I use windows10 and opencv 2.4.13 and python 2.7

I cannot find read funcation to read image from videocapture object . so I get empty frame in **im** variable
look to my code and picture:

```
webcam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
(_, im) = webcam.read() # here the funcation read() not found in auto complete
 gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

what is reason to this proplem ? 
any alterantive solve?

[picture proplem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xK82.png)

Comment: Its the editor issue, not about opencv or python. Some times, my editor get confused and doesn't show any competition. This question is not about issues with your tags and should be closed.